# C++: is std::unordered_map guaranteed to be node-based?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

What is the typical layout of `std::unordered_map<K, V>`? Are the `K` and `V` objects stored in the buckets themselves, or do the buckets store pointers to nodes containing the keys and values?

I'm trying to figure out the performance implications of using `std::unordered_map<K, V>` versus `std::unordered_map<K, V*>`. Assuming I only ever emplace and look up values, is there any reason to prefer the latter, even if the values are quite large? The only reason I can imagine is if the values are stored in-line in buckets, and need to be re-allocated each time the container is rehashed.

Is there anything in the standard that guarantees this won't happen?

Comment: They are node based. C++17 even exposes node handles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[[unord.req]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/unord.req#8):

> Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements,
>   and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate
>   pointers or references to elements.

The fact that pointers and references to elements are not invalidated by rehashing (or insertion/deletion, see /13) pretty much means that they have to be node based.

C++17 even exposes node handles so that you can transfer nodes between two `unordered_map`s.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.